# Difference between $rootScope and $rootScope.$root

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rootscope, angularjs-rootscope

Is there any difference between $rootScope and $rootScope.$root?

What is the difference between

$rootScope.global.flag = true and $rootScope.$root.global.flag = true

Do both of them access the same variable in rootscope?

If so, is there any particular situation where we have to use either of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All scopes in Angular are instances of the same prototype. As such, the global service `$rootScope` is the same type of object created for directives and passed to the link function as `$scope`, or for controllers.

The property `$root` is part of that prototype and available on all scopes.

The `$rootScope` is the first scope created by Angular. All scopes are created by using the `$new` method from an existing scope. So `$rootScope` is a special case because it's created before `angular.run()` is executed on modules.

When you check the value of `$scope.$root` it references the same instance that is provided by the root scope service for `$rootScope`.

Therefore;

```
console.log($rootScope === $scope.$root); // will print true
```

Or as in your example;

```
console.log($rootScope === $rootScope.$root); // will also print true
```

So yes, the variables in the root scope are the same no matter how you reference the root scope.

```
console.log($rootScope.global.flag); // prints true
console.log($scope.$root.global.flag); // prints true
console.log($rootScope.$root.global.flag); // prints true
```

You can also explicitly access the root scope in template expressions like this.

```
<div>{{$root.someValue}}</div>
```

There are other properties like `$parent` that let you walk up the chain of scopes, but `$parent` will be null for isolated scopes (since it has no parent).